ChromaDB and Requests compatibility
I am working on a privategpt instance but I am running into some SSL errors and dependency issues.  Running the most up to date requests and chromadb versions I get an SSL error of
requests.exceptions.SSLError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v1/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed.  

I looked around and found solutions using requests==2.27.1 and the line
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ''

This seemed to fix the SSL error but then I get an error saying chromadb doesn't work with requests<2.28.  So I am stuck in a loop of getting one error or the other depending on how I set up my packages.
Has anyone been able to get these two to work together or figure a way around the SSL error with up to date requests?  Thanks!
